# A composer's package doesn't exist anymore, and I have a copy. What can I do?

Tags: composer-php

Time ago, I installed a dependency on a Symfony project. It was the package `mograine/calendar-bundle`, but now this project doesn't exist anymore and has disappeared from github. It was a fork of another package with some modifications that I need for the project I'm working on.

Of course, I have a copy of the package (under `vendor/mograine` folder). But, currently I'm unable to run the `composer install` order, because this package doesn't exist.

And my question is: What can I do to solve this problem? Can I tell composer that this package is installed locally? If so, what should I do to install the package locally? Or I must create a github account and upload all the original files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its a normal symfony project, you can simply move it to your src folder resp. "copy past the namespace directories to the src directory" and remove it from the composer.json.

The src folder is autoloaded f.e.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
```

Take care that the namespaces and pathes are correct.

Also see here: [moving bundle from vendor to src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217321/moving-bundle-from-vendor-to-src-directory)